# multiple times function get called on click of list in navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Hi I have list in navbar as:

```
<div data-role="navbar">
            <ul id="mylist">
                <li onclick=getData() id="first"><a href="#">First</a></li>
                <li onclick=getData() id="second"><a href="#">Second</a></li>
                <li onclick=getData() id="third"><a href="#">Third</a></li>
                <li onclick=getData() id="four"><a href="#">Four</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

I have getData function as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getData()
{
    console.log ("first line in getData>>>>");
    $("#first").live("click",function()
        {
            console.log("click on first>>>");
            chkTitle=$(this).text();                
             responseData();

        });


        $("#second").live("click",function()
        {
            console.log ("click on second>>>");
            chkTitle=$(this).text();                
             responseData();

        });

        $("#third").live("click",function()
        {
            console.log("click on third>>>");
            chkTitle=$(this).text();
            responseData();

        });

        $("#four").live("click",function()
        {
            console.log("click on four>>>");
            chkTitle=$(this).text();
            responseData();


        });




    }


</script>
```

Now first time when I click on first veverything is fine. But when I click on suppose on second then it prints one time :"first line in getData>>>>" but print two times :"click on second>>>" third time it printsd three times and so on..

Everytime first line in getData>>>> is print only one time but live("click",function() data prints each time increasingly why is it so?

Comment: Because you're adding additional click handlers each time you call  `getData()`.

Comment: Just as an aside, you're _supposed_ to enclose html attributes in quotes.  Currently your function contains none.

`<li onclick=getData() id="four"><a href="#">Four</a></li>`

vs

`<li onclick="getData()" id="four"><a href="#">Four</a></li>`

Comment: @DCoderThank you for response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you are defining multiple click handlers, try this:

```
 <li id="first"><a href="#">First</a></li>
 <li id="second"><a href="#">Second</a></li>
 ...
```

```
$('#mylist li').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log("click on " + id);
    chkTitle = $(this).text();   
    responseData();     
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vVDR7/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that tightly binding to separate IDs is the best way to do this. Ideally, the function would be re-usable and act on some other information present (other than the ID) like a `data-` attribute or something else that decouples the function a little more.

It's also worth mentioning that the `.live()` function is deprecated and even before it was deprecated was generally shelved in favour of `.delegate()`. The currently "preferred" syntax uses `.on()` though `.delegate()` is still a non-deprecated alias for `.on()`.

As mentioned in other answers and comments: you don't need the `onclick` function call. Wrap the following (or undefined's) code in the document ready function and you're set.

So, those two things out of the way, even with tightly coupling to the IDs, I would bind the listener to the `ul` element like this:

```
$('#mylist').on('click', 'li', function() {
  console.log('My ID is: ' + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

or fleshing it out even further you could use switch (or a series of if/else if statements if you prefer that syntax... no difference):

```
$('#mylist').on('click', 'li', function() {
  var thisID = $(this).attr('id');
  switch (thisID) {
    case "first" :
      /* do stuff */
      break;
    case "second" : 
      /* do other stuff */
      break;
    case "third" : 
      /* do other stuff */
      break;
    case "four" : 
      /* do other stuff */
      break;
    default :
      console.log("Umm... I wasn't expecting that... when did I add more elements?");
  }
});
```